# Passing Multiple Case ID's into one input parameter as we need to update the status of all the cases to a particular status

Tags: sql-server

We need to pass multiple case id's to one input parameter thru a stored procedure. Reason being - we need to update several tables that have the case id column and update it's status. How can we accomplish this?

Ex: Case ID's (10,11,12,13,14) **All are Integers

So, we need to perform a mass update.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is one way but you need to be careful of SQL injection.

```
DECLARE @CaseIDs VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(100)

SET @CaseIDs  = '10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15'

SET @sql = 'UPDATE YourTable SET Status = ''Active'' WHERE CaseID IN (' + @CaseIDs + ')'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: I have something like this
CREATE PROCEDURE <proc_name> (
 CASE_ID  INT  
)
AS
BEGIN
 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE param_ID2 INT = (SELECT column2 FROM <table2> WHERE table2.CASE_ID IN (CASE_ID))

DECLARE param_ID3 INT = (SELECT column3 FROM < table3>WHERE table2.column2= param_id2)

I have to go to multiple tables and not every table has a CASE ID. So, I have to fetch the equivalent set of records, and then perform the update action